# Create a loop to scrape a single value through multiple URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and writing code in general so I will try to explain to the best of my abilities.

I am trying to create a list of all the "Average Wind Gust" values from a range of dates. I am using BeatifulSoup in Python 3. The following code returns the exact value I need, but I want to do the same for every date from January 1st, 2016 to May 1st, 2021.

```
float(list(soup.find_all("span", {'class':'wu-value wu-value-to'}))[-3].text)
```

I know that for every URL, the value I need is in the same position, so this code should work, however, I see two ways of doing this but I don't know how to execute any of those.

The first one would just use code to press the "next" button that takes us to the next date, as seen in the screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AorpN.png).

The second one would create a list containing all the dates I need, and then it would loop through a formatted URL like the following and create a list of all the URLs. The formatted URL has a variable called "init_value" twice (that's just how the URL is).

And then there would just be a second loop that uses the created URL list to do the scrape.

```
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/dashboard/pws/IPANAMPU2/graph/{init_date}/{init_date}/daily' 

url.format(init_date="2016-01-1")
```

I think the first way is easier and simpler, but I don't know if it can be done.
Please let me know which way you think is better and how would you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is making Ajax request to external URL to obtain the values. You can use this example to simulate it:

```py
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = "https://www.wunderground.com/dashboard/pws/IPANAMPU2/graph/{init_date}/{init_date}/daily"
api_url = "https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/history/daily"

params = {
    "stationId": "IPANAMPU2",
    "format": "json",
    "units": "e",
    "startDate": "20160103",
    "endDate": "20160104",
    "numericPrecision": "decimal",
    "apiKey": "e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525",
}


d = datetime(2016, 1, 1)
dt = timedelta(days=1)

for i in range(10):
    ds = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    params["startDate"] = ds
    params["endDate"] = ds
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

    # uncomment this to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    print(ds, data["observations"][0]["imperial"]["windgustAvg"])
    d += dt
```

Prints:

```
20160101 27.1
20160102 23.5
20160103 18.6
20160104 16.9
20160105 16.0
20160106 17.4
20160107 19.2
20160108 19.6
20160109 20.0
20160110 20.5
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me. How would you adapt it for more values? I tried changing the range and storing the values in lists. It works for small numbers (below 100), but after that it gives me an "IndexError: list index out of range" error, and I need it to store values for 1978 days.

Comment: @DanielG Have you tried to increase the value in `for i in range(<insert value here>):` ?

Comment: Hello, yes I did, I just found out that some dates did not have the values which was the reason for the error. I just wrote a "try" and "except" to write them as NA. Thank you so much for your help.